# Postgresql database on Hekoru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I can't setup database on heroku. Local i just type rake db:reset and that's all, but on heroku when i type heroku pg:reset DATABASE it say my something like this

```
 ▸    WARNING: Destructive action
 ▸    postgresql-flat-69104 will lose all of its data
 ▸    
 ▸    To proceed, type cocktail-tour or re-run this command
 ▸    with --confirm cocktail-tour

> cocktail-tour
Resetting postgresql-flat-69104... done
```

but database still not working. So i get heroku logs here is they.

```
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450646+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.450586 #4] FATAL -- : [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/blog-post.css"):
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450815+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450812+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450813+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450814+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450814+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450708+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.450650 #4] FATAL -- : [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717]   
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450816+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450808+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.450734 #4] FATAL -- : [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450816+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450810+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450817+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450811+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450818+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450812+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450818+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450819+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450820+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450820+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450821+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450822+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450823+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450821+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.450823+00:00 app[web.1]: [0080e171-5a3f-497f-ac7b-d2700fcd2717] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.932433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/blog-post.css" host=cocktail-tour.herokuapp.com request_id=8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e fwd="78.137.22.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https
2017-04-05T21:08:40.921868+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.921771 #4]  INFO -- : [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] Started GET "/css/blog-post.css" for 78.137.22.84 at 2017-04-05 21:08:40 +0000
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922713+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.922649 #4] FATAL -- : [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e]   
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922772+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.922715 #4] FATAL -- : [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/blog-post.css"):
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922825+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.922772 #4] FATAL -- : [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e]   
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922950+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.922851 #4] FATAL -- : [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922951+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922952+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922954+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922954+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922955+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922955+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922956+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922957+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922958+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922958+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922959+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922959+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922960+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922961+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922961+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922963+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922962+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922963+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922964+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922965+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.922965+00:00 app[web.1]: [8be51a05-cb92-4b4c-880e-9242f066f87e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.940520+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.940435 #4]  INFO -- : [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] Started GET "/css/bootstrap.min.css" for 78.137.22.84 at 2017-04-05 21:08:40 +0000
2017-04-05T21:08:40.978853+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.978723 #4] FATAL -- : [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/bootstrap.min.css"):
2017-04-05T21:08:40.947120+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.947047 #4] FATAL -- : [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd]   
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980642+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.980590 #4] FATAL -- : [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd]   
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980958+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:40.980893 #4] FATAL -- : [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980962+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980963+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980964+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980965+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980966+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980966+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980967+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980968+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980969+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980970+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980969+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980971+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980972+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980972+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980973+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980974+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980974+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980975+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980976+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980976+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.980977+00:00 app[web.1]: [ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-04-05T21:08:40.993622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=cocktail-tour.herokuapp.com request_id=ea1240a9-38a5-4753-b0b5-cb0282fe8cdd fwd="78.137.22.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=66ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https
2017-04-05T21:08:41.213397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2" host=cocktail-tour.herokuapp.com request_id=30352405-cdc3-4395-b993-b9914f4c3023 fwd="78.137.22.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2017-04-05T21:08:43.698584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cocktail-tour.herokuapp.com request_id=edf5aa29-efaa-468e-ba74-40893af6c7b0 fwd="78.137.22.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2017-04-05T21:08:43.817648+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.817547 #4]  INFO -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7] Started GET "/recipes/new" for 78.137.22.84 at 2017-04-05 21:08:43 +0000
2017-04-05T21:08:43.818715+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.818645 #4]  INFO -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7] Processing by RecipesController#new as HTML
2017-04-05T21:08:43.867739+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.867506 #4]  INFO -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868694+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.868624 #4] FATAL -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7]   
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868790+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.868703 #4] FATAL -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "recipes" does not exist
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868792+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"recipes"'::regclass
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868793+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868794+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868795+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868796+00:00 app[web.1]:              (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868796+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868797+00:00 app[web.1]:                      col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868798+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868798+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868799+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"recipes"'::regclass
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868799+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868800+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868801+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868857+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.868798 #4] FATAL -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7]   
2017-04-05T21:08:43.868929+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-04-05T21:08:43.868870 #4] FATAL -- : [370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7] app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:11:in `new'
2017-04-05T21:08:43.861904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/recipes/new" host=cocktail-tour.herokuapp.com request_id=370928a4-4ae3-4e51-a9c6-7a8e4ce59fe7 fwd="78.137.22.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=61ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https
```

Comment: `rake db:reset` drops the database and recreates it. This is not what you want.

Comment: what did you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you need to run migrations, run:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

Comment: I struggled initially with this concept.  Once you've committed and pushed your local files to production you still need to create the tables in your production database. As mentioned by @neydroid. `heroku run rails db:migrate` is the command that will do this.